# manipulate pytest commandline param for only one test

Tags: python, fabric, pytest

Is it possible to set the -s command-line parameter of pytest via a fixture or any other method?
What I want to achieve is to enable the -s (capture=no) option for exactly one of my tests?

I am thinking of a way to manipulate this option from within the test, or via a fixture.

To give an example of a test that needs disabled capturing here is a really simple test:

```
from fabric.state import env
from fabric.operations import run

class TestCapture:
    def test_fabric(self):

        env.user = '<ssh_username>'
        env.password = '<ssh_password>' 
        env.host_string = '<hostname>'

        who = run('whoami').stdout # use fabric command run to invoke whoami on <hostname>

        assert who == '<username>'
```

In this test fabric is used to login on another machine via ssh, and run the whoami command. The result should be the name of the login user.

This test fails, if pytest's capturing is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manipulate this using `request.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager').suspendcapture()` and `.resumecapture()`.

But this is a rather rare usecase which should not be needed normally.  The only two cases I can think of right now for which this is reasonable are in the pdb and pytest-timeout plugins.  So explaining your usecase a bit more might be helpful.

Comment: I have code that uses the fabric framework, which I want to test. This test fails, if the output is captured. I don't want to disable capturing of the output for all tests though.

Comment: Also I am not sure how to use the code you provided. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I added the example to the question